Are the 'since' and 'until' parameters not working in the Meta Threads Insights API?
I'm currently working on a side project using the Meta Threads API. I'm trying to use the Media Insights API to build a feature that retrieves daily insights. However, even when I include the since and until parameters, the response always returns the same data—it only gives me the current insight values.
The image below is a screenshot from my side project.
screenshot of my work
Here’s the URL and parameters I’m using:

URL: https://graph.threads.net/v1.0/{media-id}/insights
Parameters:

metric: views, likes, replies, reposts, quotes
access_token: [hidden]
since: 1726139641


until: 1726185599

I also tried using the since and until parameters with the YYYY-MM-DD format, but it still returns the same result. For example:

since: 2024-09-13
until: 2024-09-14

Am I missing something, or is this an API bug? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I wanted to see the daily changes in metrics like views, likes, and replies.
